# windows 8 - sqlite issue - update of database table value - property issue

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8

I am developing a metro style app for windows 8 with c#, XAML and SQLite. Currently I am facing an issue. I am using a updating or storing few details but when I try to write the data into SQLite using below code

```
StorageFolder DataFolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("data");
StorageFile DataFile = await DataFolder.GetFileAsync("Test.sqlite");

if ( DataFile != null)
{
    var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DataFile .Path, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(db);
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Test SET Value=1000 WHERE Id = 5";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But when the program is debug and when the cursor came on “cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()”

> An exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in
>   SQLite_Sample.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: ReadOnly If there is a handler for this
>   exception, the program may be safely continued.

I want to set permission programmatically for this SQLite file for read write functionality.

Can anyone guide me for this?

Comment: did you open the connection? Normally you would have to call db.Open();

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you didn't open the connection.

```
if ( DataFile != null) 
{ 
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DataFile.Path, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite))
    {
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(db); 
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Test SET Value=1000 WHERE Id = 5"; 
        db.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
}
```

and remember to use parameterized commands.